# Characterization of Faithfully Flatness

Tags: commutative-algebra

I know that for a flat $R$-module $M$ the property beeing ***fathfully flat*** is in most literature is characterized via

(*) for every complex of $R$-modules $N_1→N_2→N_3$ is exact if and only if the sequence $M⊗_R N_1→M⊗_ RN_2→M⊗_R N_3$ is exact.

I would like to see why and how to see that- if we assume that $M$ is a $R$-algebra(!) - faithfully flatness can be equivalently characterized by the condition that the corresponding map between Spectra

(**) $$\operatorname{Spec}(A) \to \operatorname{Spec}(R)$$ is surjective?

Comment: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00HQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classical result of commutative algebra, which can be found in various books, such as the Corollary 2.20 in Liu's *Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves*, the Exercise 3.16 of Atiyah & MacDonald's *Introduction to Commutative Algebra* and the Theorem 3 in Chap.1 of Matsumura's *Commutative Algebra*. Suppose that the ring homomorphism $f\colon A\to B$ is flat.
$\newcommand{\m}{\mathfrak m}$
$\newcommand{\spec}{\operatorname{Spec}}$
$\newcommand{\p}{\mathfrak p}$
To see this, you may need to know firstly these results about faithful flatness:

- $f$ is faithfully flat iff for each $A$-module $M\neq 0$, $M\otimes_A B\neq 0$.
- $f$ is faithfully flat iff $\m B\neq B$ for any maximal ideal $\m$.

The following proof is essentially an excerpt of Matsumura's book. Let $f\colon A\to B$ be a flat ring homomorphism. Then

- **$f$ is faithfully flat $\Longrightarrow$ $f^*\colon \spec(B)\to\spec(A)$ is surjective.** To this end, for any $\p\in\spec(A)$, we have $\p B_\p\neq B_\p$, where $B_\p=A_\p\otimes_A B$ (otherwise $0=B_\p/\p B_\p=(A_\p/ \p A_\p)\otimes_A B\neq 0$, a contradiction). Pick a maximal ideal $\m\supset\p B_\p$ of $B_\p$. Since the following diagram is commutative
  $$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD}
  A@>{f}>> B\\
  @V{\varphi_A}VV@VV{\varphi_B=\varphi_A\otimes \mathrm{id}_B}V\\ 
  A_\p@>{f_\p}>> B_\p\end{CD}$$where $\varphi_A\colon A\to A_\p$ is the localization map, it suffices to take $P=\varphi_B^{-1}(\m)$. Indeed, since $\p A_\p\subset f_\p^{-1}(\m)$ and $\p A_\p$ is a maximal ideal, $f_\p^{-1}(\m)=\p A_\p$. Then it follows that$$
  f^*(P)=f^{-1}(P)=f^{-1}(\varphi_B^{-1}(\m))=\varphi_A^{-1}(f_\p^{-1}(\m))=\varphi_A^{-1}(\p A_\p)=\p.
  $$
- **$f^*$ is surjective $\Longrightarrow$ $f$ is faithfully flat.** For each maximal ideal $\m$ of $A$, there is a $P\in\spec(B)$ such that $f^*(P)=\m$. Thus for any maximal ideal $\m'\supset P$ of $B$, we have $f^*(\m')=\m$, i.e., $\m'$ lies over $\m$, which implies $\m B\neq B$. The arbitrariness of $\m$ entails the faithful flatness of $f$.